# SAS - timestamp with zone information

Tags: oracle, sas

I get the following data from Oracle (timestamp with zone) -

1. 22.11.13 04:08:00,100 EUROPE/ROME
2. 28.12.13 03:06:40,000 +01:00

Is there a generic way to parse this information and use it in SAS?

Comment: Do you want to see only date and time in SAS?

Comment: If it is possible I would want the entire data. Else I would be happy with just date and time.

Comment: The `substr` function could be used to strip out the datetime part. `Datetime = substr(timestamp, 1,17)`. This could then be read in using the input function

Comment: Also there is the B8601DZw. Format in SAS to keep date time and time zone...

Comment: @andrey_sz: The problem with B8601DZw is that it will not recognize the first scenario where in I have EUROPE/ROME. Also, note that we have millisecond in the data.